# Updating a parent object / array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am would like to update some nested data in `decodedObj` (See below). Basically at the moment I am drilling down to an array in the object called "Indications" then further finding an object in that array with a key value pair of "ID": "inID" (passed from the url). I am then objected another key-value pair in the same object from that. Now where I am getting stuck is then updating the value in the IndicationsObj.
I am needing to update the indicationsObj because the purpose of this script is to actually update the JSON file.

```
$jsonData = file_get_contents("./data/ComUserJsonDummy.json");
$decodedObj = json_decode($jsonData, true);
$IndicationsObj = json_encode($decodedObj["Indications"]);

// Filter the Indications object based of the ID
$foundObj = array_filter(
    json_decode($IndicationsObj),
    function ($obj) {
        return $obj->ID == $_GET["inID"];
    }
);

// Update the columnName of the found object
$foundObj[0]->CommonName = $_GET["columnName"];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can greatly simplify your code by using [`array_search`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) and [`array_column`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) to find the `ID` value in `$decodedObj` and then set the corresponding `CommonName`, *before* creating `$IndicationsObj`:

```
$jsonData = file_get_contents("./data/ComUserJsonDummy.json");
$decodedObj = json_decode($jsonData, true);
if (($key = array_search($_GET["inID"], array_column($decodedObj['Indications'], 'ID'))) !== false) {
    $decodedObj['Indications'][$key]['CommonName'] = $_GET["columnName"];
}
$IndicationsObj = json_encode($decodedObj["Indications"]);
```

Comment: This works but when attempting to echo out $decodedObj it returns literally the word "Array", when is I wrap that in `json_encode` nothing returned.

Comment: @TomDickson you can't `echo $decodedObj` as it is an array. But `echo json_encode($decodedObj)` should give a valid string

Comment: @TomDickson can you share some more information to help debug the problem? A sample of the JSON would make it easy for me to test the code.

Answer (score 1):

You can make the find and update at the same time.

```
foreach($IndicationsObj as &$obj){
    if($obj->ID == $_GET["inID"]){
        $obj[0]->CommonName = $_GET["columnName"];
    }
}
```